# Insert multiple objects into the database dynamically using reflection and Ado.net

Tags: c#, generics, recursion, reflection, insert

I am trying to solve it for a long time. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Basically, I need to insert multiple objects into the database dynamically. The method should work on 3 or 3+ level relationship. Like - The method will be able to insert House object which holds the list of room object, and room object holds the list of furniture object. Each of the objects will enter into the database in a recursive process. That's mean the method will call itself if it finds a generic list.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var house1 = new House()
            {
                Id = 1,
                HouseName = "Hasan's villa",
                HouseAddress = "Riyadh",
                Rooms = new List<Room>() { new Room() { Id = 01, Rent = 1200,

                    Furnitures = new List<Furniture>() { new Furniture() { Id = 001, FurnitureName = "Table", Price = 45 },
                                                       { new Furniture() { Id = 002, FurnitureName = "Bookshelf", Price = 55 } } } },

                    new Room(){Id = 02, Rent = 1500, Furnitures = new List<Furniture> {new Furniture(){Id = 003 , FurnitureName = "Almari", Price = 75}} }

                }
            };

var connectionString = "Server=SQLEXPRESS//FERTILE-FIEL;Database=ASPNETB4;Trusted_Connection=True;";
            var dataOperation = new DataOperation<House>(connectionString);

            dataOperation.Insert(house1);
    }


class DataOperation<T> : IDataOperation<T> where T : Entity
    {
        private readonly string _connectionString;
        private SqlConnection connection;

        public DataOperation(string connectionString)
        {
            _connectionString = connectionString;
        }
        public void Insert(T item)
        {
            EntityMaker entityMaker = new EntityMaker();
            entityMaker.InsertEntity(item);
        }
    }



class EntityMaker
    {
        public object genericProp { get; set; }
        public void InsertEntity(object entity)
        {
            Type type = entity.GetType();
            string name = type.Name;

    

    var propertyNames = new ArrayList();
    
            var propertyValue = new ArrayList();

//Need to make the sql dynamic. I have just hard coded it for now.

string sql = "INSERT INTO " + name + " (" + propertyNames[0]+',' + propertyNames[1]+','+ propertyNames [3]+") 
    VALUES(" + propertyValues[0]+',' + propertyValues[1]+',' + propertyValues[2]+");";

        var properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);

        foreach (var prop in properties)
        {

            if (prop.PropertyType.IsGenericType)
            {
                genericProp = prop.PropertyType;
                Type genType = (Type)genericProp;
                var types = genType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

                var genName = types.Name;

                InsertEntity(genName);
            }
            else
            {
                var propName = prop.Name;
                var propValue = prop.GetValue(entity).ToString();

                if (propName != null)
                {
                    propertyNames.Add(propName).ToString();
                    propertyValue.Add(propValue).ToString();
                }
            }

        }
```

Thanks for considering the problem.

Comment: Is this accurate regarding your db schema: tables: `House`, `Room` and `Furniture`. relationships: `House --> Room` and `Room --> Furniture`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Its House > Room > Furniture > 3 level relationship. The method should work on 3+ level also.

Comment: Sorry, I missed to include one Class - DataOperation<T>

Comment: I have a solution that I use in production. It steers clear of dynamic sql, favoring type and injection safety by utilizing `SQL User Defined Table Types`. Is that a solution that would interest you, or is Dynamic SQL / Recursive part of the requirements?

Comment: It would be great if you could share that solution.